# How to add a "static" column to a google chart based on a JSON table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a google chart in a wrapper that is based on a JSON table (as the data source)

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTableA>);
```

How can I with a click of a button add a column with a static value in it?

what I mean by that is that I will have a variable (let's assume that the value of that variable is 4) and if the JSON table has 5 rows all five rows in the NEW data will have "4" in that column... if the JSON table has 20 rows all 20 rows in the NEW data will have "4" in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++)` combined with `dataTable.setCell()` should do the trick:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var addStatic; // global variable to hold click function

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2013', 1000, 400],
    ['2014', 1170, 460],
    ['2015', 660, 1120]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);

  // this function adds a colmn and sets a constant value in each row of that column, 
  //   independently of the number of rows in the table
  // then redraw the chart.
  // no var: the addStatic variable must be global for the button's click handler to access it
  addStatic = function() {
    var staticValue = Math.random() * 1000;
    data.addColumn('number', 'Constant');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      data.setCell(i, data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1, staticValue);
    }
    chart.draw(data);
  }

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<button onclick="addStatic();">Add Static Column</button> 
&lt;== click this button to add a column with a static value in it
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: we meet again :) thank you Paul. Thank you VERY much.